# Undefined method `find_by_name' for Gem::Specification:Class

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, puppet, rspec-puppet

I created the `spec/` structure for my puppet module using `rspec-puppet-init`. However, I am getting this strange error: **Undefined method find_by_name for Gem::Specification:Class**. I am running `ruby 1.8.7` for RHEL6.

```
$ rake spec
(in /etc/puppet/modules/profiles)
rake aborted!
undefined method `find_by_name' for Gem::Specification:Class
/etc/puppet/modules/profiles/Rakefile:22
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I then ran it with `--trace` and get this:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `find_by_name' for Gem::Specification:Class
/etc/puppet/modules/profiles/Rakefile:22
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2382:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2382:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2067:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2015:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1999:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2067:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1997:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

In my Rakefile (this is autogenerated):

```
require 'rake'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

desc "Run all RSpec code examples"
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:rspec) do |t|
  t.rspec_opts = File.read("spec/spec.opts").chomp || ""
end

SPEC_SUITES = (Dir.entries('spec') - ['.', '..','fixtures']).select {|e| File.directory? "spec/#{e}" }
namespace :rspec do
  SPEC_SUITES.each do |suite|
    desc "Run #{suite} RSpec code examples"
    RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(suite) do |t|
      t.pattern = "spec/#{suite}/**/*_spec.rb"
      t.rspec_opts = File.read("spec/spec.opts").chomp || ""
    end
  end
end
task :default => :rspec

begin
  if Gem::Specification::find_by_name('puppet-lint')
    require 'puppet-lint/tasks/puppet-lint'
    PuppetLint.configuration.ignore_paths = ["spec/**/*.pp", "vendor/**/*.pp"]
    task :default => [:rspec, :lint]
  end
rescue Gem::LoadError
end
```

Any idea what is wrong? I am not a ruby expert by any means.

My RubyGems Environment:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /home/staticx/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: what goes into line #22 in your rakefile ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: `if Gem::Specification::find_by_name('puppet-lint')`

Comment: have you tried `gem update --system` because you are running a fairly old version current version on my machine is `2.2.2`

Comment: @engineersmnky: That seemed to work! see my answer below

Comment: Great if you look at the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Specification.html) seems `find_by_name` was introduced into `Gem::Specifications` in `1.9.3` so I figured this might be the issue.

Comment: @engineersmnky: Cool, I am very new to Ruby so thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [@engineersmnky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978251/engineersmnky), I ran the following:

```
$ gem update --system
```

I then had to re-run these commands:

```
$ sudo gem install rake
$ sudo gem install puppetlabs_spec_helper
$ sudo gem install puppet-lint
```